# Derivative in $L_2$ given difference sequence is $\ell_2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am wondering if there is a criterion for a function so that the following is satisfied.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$\underset{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum|f(j+1)-f(j)|^2<\infty$$
that is $(f(j+1)-f(j))\in\ell_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
What would be a suitable condition on $f$ to make $f'\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Assuming $f$ is continuous, the above sum by the mean value theorem is $$\underset{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum|f'(\xi_j)|^2$$
for some $\xi_j\in[j,j+1]$.

This sum being finite is easily shown to be insufficient to imply the function's derivative is in $L_2$ by considering $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)/(\pi x)$.

I know from some  reading that a necessary and sufficient condition for $f'\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ is that
$$\underset{h>0}\sup\underset{j\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum\left|\frac{f((j+1)h)-f(jh)}{h}\right|^2<\infty$$
I am just wondering if some extra conditions on $f$ would eliminate the necessity of summing over $h\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect to have information about the derivative if you only know about values of the function in a set of points all far from each other.

For example, you can set $f$ to be zero at every $j\in\mathbb Z$, thus satisfying your condition, and yet you are free to decide on the behavior in each interval $(j,j+1)$ so that the derivative can be as wild as you wish. You could have, say
$$
f(x)=(x-n)^2(n+1-x)^2nx,\ \ x\in[n,n+1).
$$
Then $f$ is differentiable, $f(j)=f'(j)=0$ for all $j\in\mathbb Z$, and $f'$ goes beyond both $n$ and $-n$ on each interval $(n,n+1)$. So $f'$ is not even bounded.

Comment: I agree with the idea, though your counterexample is not quite what I am considering, as the function itself is not bounded on the line.  On further consideration, though I can think of a counterexample in which the function is bounded.  Take a $C^\infty$ bump function that is 0 and has 0 slope at all the integers and make it peak at 1 at all the half-integers.  Then $f$ is close to a triangle on each interval, and $\int|f'|^2$ would be close to 1 on each piece $[n,n+1]$, and so is not $L_2$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do, but I didn't pay much attention to the formula. You do it as you say, but in each interval you can get the function to be steeper (and still bounded by $1$). So you get a function satisfying your condition and where $f'$ is unbounded.